# ASP.NET Web.ApI adding stuff I don't get

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

for some reason, my simple .getJSON method is adding some extra stuff to my json I don't get. I think I've done a very simple implementation.  Below is the JSON and my JavaScript.

It's all the k__BackingField.   Who is helping me with that?

```
 [{"<CodeCampYearId>k__BackingField":7,"<Attendeesid>k__BackingField":1124,"<SessionLevel_id>k__BackingField":2,"<SponsorId>k__Ba    



$(document).ready(function () {
        // Send an AJAX request
        $.getJSON("api/session/GetAll",
        function (data) {
            // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                //debugger;

                // Format the text to display.
                //var str = val.Name + ': $' + val.Price;
                var str = 'abcd';

                // Add a list item for the product.
                $('<li/>', { text: str })
                .appendTo($('#products'));
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the action you are calling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, it turned out that I needed to add `[DataContract]` to the class and to each of the properties `[DataMember]`.

Youssef's comment above reminded me it was a serialization problem so thanks for that.
The suggestion however would not resolve.

The project I'm using this in may have an older `NewtonSoft serializer` though which may have caused an issue.  I still now have my `[serializable]` attribute and it works as I would expect with that as long as I include the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` on each property.

Answer (score 8):

Your class is likely `[Serializable]` which causes fields to be serialized. You can either:

- Remove the `[Serializable]` attribute
- Or ask the `JSON` formatter to ignore the `[Serializable]` semantics with this line:

  ```
  (DefaultContractResolver)config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.
  SerializerSettings.ContractResolver).IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;
  ```